# How to center page at page-load even when Javascript is off?

Tags: html, css, layout

if I am designing a page with center-layout, kind of like Yahoo Answers, how can I do it? I could have used Javascript to catch the screen width at page-load, and make changes to the main div accordingly, but the user may have Javascript turned off, so how to do it in that case?

Comment: Is Javascript necessary? Usually this is done with CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just did not know how to do it with CSS only.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  Also, make sure you give answer credit if your question was answered.  It's a courtesy.

Comment: Well, I did credit all useful answers on this page. Is it the nor here to credit every answer, or credit useful answers only? I am a regular user in Dreamincode, there users credit only useful answers...

Comment: You should mark just one question as "answered".  That way it gets promoted to the top of the page for easier reference for those who read the question later.  Look for the checkmark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put your content in a `<div>` and set it to a fixed width and `margin:auto`

Comment: For that container needs to have explicit width also set wont work otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
#container { 
   margin-left:50%; 
   margin-right:50%; 
}
```

**In case you KNOW width, just use `margin: 0 auto;`**:

```
#container { 
   width:500px;
   margin:0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: `margin:auto` is a simpler way to accomplish the same thing

Comment: @JohnConde: True added but it seems he does not know `width` beforehand without which `margin:auto` wont help

Comment: No no, I know the width, so I will use **margin:auto** as well as **width:500px**.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer :) http://jsfiddle.net/eJJKf/